# c# - different function override based on parameters' type

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, overloading

I'm playing with `AST` and I want to implement a class `Visitor` that traverse my tree and returns a value.
I tried in this way but my code doesn't compile:

```
abstract class ASTVisitor<T> {
  public abstract T Visit(SumExpr e);
  public abstract T Visit(ProductExpr e);
  public abstract T Visit(ConstantExpr e);
  public abstract T Visit(SymbolExpr e); 
}

class DerivateVisitor : ASTVisitor<ASTExpr> {

  public override ASTExpr Visit(SumExpr e){
    return new SumExpr(
      Visit(e.A),
      Visit(e.B));
  }
  public override ASTExpr Visit(ProductExpr e){
    return new SumExpr(
      new ProductExpr(Visit(e.A), e.B),
      new ProductExpr(Visit(e.B), e.A));
  }
  public override ASTExpr Visit(ConstantExpr e){
    return new ConstantExpr(0);
  }
  public override ASTExpr Visit(SymbolExpr e) {
    return new ConstantExpr(1);
  }
}
```

`SumExpr`, `ProductExpr`, `ConstantExpr`, `SymbolExpr` Implementation:

```
class ASTExpr{}
class ProductExpr : ASTExpr{
  public ASTExpr A, B;
  public ProductExpr(ASTExpr a, ASTExpr b) => 
    (A, B) = (a, b);
  public override string ToString() => $"({A.ToString()}) * ({B.ToString()})";    

}

class ConstantExpr : ASTExpr {
  public double Value;
  public ConstantExpr(double v) => Value = v;
  public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();

}

class SymbolExpr : ASTExpr {
  public string Name;
  private static Dictionary<string, SymbolExpr> Symbols = new Dictionary<string, SymbolExpr>();
  private SymbolExpr(string v) { 
    Name = v;
  }

  public static SymbolExpr Create(string Name){
    if(Symbols.ContainsKey(Name)) return Symbols[Name];
    return Symbols[Name] = new SymbolExpr(Name);
  }

  public override string ToString() => $"Symbol({Name})";

}

class SumExpr : ASTExpr{
  public ASTExpr A, B;
  public SumExpr(ASTExpr a, ASTExpr b) => 
    (A, B) = (a, b);

  public override string ToString() => $"({A.ToString()}) + ({B.ToString()})";
}
```

`SumExpr`, `ProductExpr`, `ConstantExpr`, `SymbolExpr` inherit from `ASTExpr`.
Why this doesn't work? and how I can get this behaviours?

this is the compilation errors:

```
exit status 1
main.cs(56,7): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `ASTVisitor<ASTExpr>.Visit(SumExpr)' has some invalid arguments
main.cs(45,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
main.cs(56,13): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `ASTExpr' expression to type `SumExpr'
main.cs(57,7): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `ASTVisitor<ASTExpr>.Visit(SumExpr)' has some invalid arguments
main.cs(45,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
main.cs(57,15): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `ASTExpr' expression to type `SumExpr'
main.cs(61,23): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `ASTVisitor<ASTExpr>.Visit(SumExpr)' has some invalid arguments
main.cs(45,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
main.cs(61,31): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `ASTExpr' expression to type `SumExpr'
main.cs(62,23): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `ASTVisitor<ASTExpr>.Visit(SumExpr)' has some invalid arguments
main.cs(45,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
main.cs(62,31): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `ASTExpr' expression to type `SumExpr'
Compilation failed: 8 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What kind of compilation error you've got

Comment: I add the errors

Comment: Please include the message(s) from your error list in Visual Studio when you try to compile that code.

Comment: Please, provide ASTExpr and SumExpr definitions. How are they connected?

Comment: is it also necessary the implementation of the SumExpr, ProductExpr, ConstantExpr, SymbolExpr and ASTExpr classes?

Comment: It's necessary to understand classes references

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

```
class SumExpr : ASTExpr
{
    public ASTExpr A, B;
    public SumExpr(ASTExpr a, ASTExpr b) =>
      (A, B) = (a, b);

    public override string ToString() => $"({A.ToString()}) + ({B.ToString()})";
}
```

and

```
public override ASTExpr Visit(SumExpr e)
    {
        return new SumExpr(
          Visit(e.A),
          Visit(e.B));
    }
```

e.A is ASTExpr but there is no method Visit which could be called for ASTExpr.

Type of object is defined during compilation not in runtime.

Add the following method

```
public override ASTExpr Visit(ASTExpr e)
    {
        if (e as SumExpr != null)
            return Visit(e as SumExpr);

        if (e as ProductExpr != null)
            return Visit(e as ProductExpr);

        if (e as ConstantExpr != null)
            return Visit(e as ConstantExpr);

        if (e as SymbolExpr != null)
            return Visit(e as SymbolExpr);

        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

Comment: but if I add an override for `ASTExpr` all calls to Visit will refer to that override. quite right?

Comment: No, compilator should find the most suitable method. You can check by clicking GotoDefinition context menu item in VS

Comment: You can stick to https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionVisitor.cs as an example of the visitor implementation and get implementation details from there. The code provided looks more straightforward, so going with Visit methods with different names looks more transparent to me

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code, you are calling `ASTVisitor<ASTExpr>.Visit` with invalid arguments (e.A) where as it is expecting (e).

`Visit` method is expecting an object of one of these (`SumExpr , ProductExpr, ConstantExpr, SymbolExpr`) and you are passing `e.A` which is `ASTExpr`

```
public override ASTExpr Visit(SumExpr e){
    return new SumExpr(
      Visit(e.A),     // You are passing ASTExpr where as SumExpr is expected
      Visit(e.B));    // You are passing ASTExpr where as SumExpr is expected
  }
```

This definitely changes your logic which you will have to work on.

Comment: I just made changes to arguments. Will update my code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slight improvement on @Sergey Prosin's answer. Using `as` works, but is slower, as each use first checks if the type matches. Instead, you can either assign the `as` expression result to a variable and use it then or use the new `is` pattern matching syntax:

```
public override ASTExpr Visit(ASTExpr e)
{
    if (e is SumExpr sum)
        return Visit(sum);

    if (e is ProductExpr product)
        return Visit(product);

    if (e is ConstantExpr constant)
        return Visit(constant);

    if (e is SymbolExpr symbol)
        return Visit(symbol);

    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Or **even cooler**, the `switch` pattern matching:

```
public override ASTExpr Visit(ASTExpr e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case SumExpr sum:
           return Visit(sum); 
        case ProductExpr product:
           return Visit(product);
        case ConstantExpr constant:
           return Visit(constant);
        case SymbolExpr symbol:
           return Visit(symbol);
        default:
           throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```